# Is .bind() or .click() better to bind a click event handler?

Tags: jquery

To add a click event handler to an element, is `.bind('click')` or `.click` better? What makes the difference? Any performance aspects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. Internally, `click` just calls `on`, and `bind` also just calls `on`. So for a very minor speed increase, just use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#someId").on("click", function () {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Here's the relevant part of the jQuery 1.7.2 [source for the `.click()` method](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click):

```
return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on(name, null, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
```

And the [source of the `.bind()` method](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.bind):

```
return this.on(types, null, data, fn);
```

---

*If you're using jQuery below version 1.7...*

Note that the `.on()` method was introduced in jQuery 1.7. If you are using an older version, `.click()` will internally just call `.bind()` instead. Here's the [source of `.click()` from 1.6.2](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click):

```
return arguments.length > 0 ? this.bind(name, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
```

Comment: is live deprecated now in 1.7?

Comment: @refhat - Yes, [`.live()` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com) as of 1.7. Use `on` instead.

Comment: @PeeHaa - What do you mean? You call it as shown in the answer.

Comment: @PeeHaa - Hmm. Your JSPerf test ([modified to not delegate the event](http://jsperf.com/bind-click-vs-on-click/2)) is very interesting. Not sure why that's the result yet.

Comment: That's the reason I tested it. `.delegate()` used to use `.live()` internally which had the same effect in previous version. http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on

Comment: @PeeHaa - In Firefox, `on` seems to be quickest. In Chrome, it's slowest. However in the real word it's going to make no difference whatsoever, so I would just recommend using whichever method you are most comfortable with!

Comment: @JamesAllardice Ofc we are talking about stupid micro optimizations here, but it's interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @PeeHaa - Yeah it is very interesting. When I get a chance I'll try to run some more tests and see if I can work out what's going on.