# How to improve this jquery code?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){

    $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn").click(function(e){
        $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn").removeClass("active");
        _this = $(this);
        _this.addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

I add 'click' event listener to `#available_job_types .job_type_btn`, set active on current clicked element. I want to know if there is a way to improve this in the function:

```
$("#available_job_types .job_type_btn").removeClass("active");
```

How to not repeat jquery selector `$("#available_job_types .job_type_btn")` ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it will not help any users in the future and is about code review. Asking it on codereview.stackexchange.com might be better.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will not do this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){

var $btn=  $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn");
    $btn.click(function(e){
       $btn.removeClass("active");
        _this = $(this); // if you use one time this then there is no need to make an variable to store $(this)
        _this.addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    var $job_type_btns = $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn").click(function(e){
        $job_type_btns.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are trying to remove the `active` class from the element which was **previously clicked**. If so, then why not storing the previous element in the function object itself and remove it on next click instead of removing the `active` class from all the elements?

Something like this:

*The below code is not tested* (It is just for logic)

```
$(function(){
    $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn").click(jobType);  //calls jobType function

    function jobType(e){
        if(jobType.prevEl){  //checks if the click function is called before
            $(jobType.prevEl).removeClass("active");    //removing the class from the previously clicked element.
        }        
        _this = $(this);
        _this.addClass("active");
        jobType.prevEl = _this;  // storing the current clicked element as previous clicked element (being ready for next click)
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The above code gives you better performance and also makes sense. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can remove repeat query selector  $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn") as following and it is better to use 'bind'

and no need to mention css class name when you remove css class

```
 var element = $("#available_job_types .job_type_btn");
    element.bind('click', function () {
        element.removeClass();
        element.addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: Could you tell me why "bind click" is better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429089/is-bind-or-click-better-to-bind-a-click-event-handler